# Realtime subscribe for comments on facebook page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I am using the koala gem in ruby to access the facebook api. I used the method as described [here](http://cowjumpedoverthecommodore64.blogspot.in/2011/06/realtime-facebook-updates-with-rails.html), to create new subscription for facebook page feed as 
updates.subscribe ("page", "feed", callback, verify_token).
Although it successfully creates a subscription however when I make some activity on fb page(like or comment), I still don't get any notifications.

FYI, for testing if subscriptions are even working for me, I tested it with another subscription for user feed and seems to be working fine. However for page feed it doesn't give me any response at all.

Comment: Not sure if RTU for `feed` is even supposed to deliver new comments … or if might just be _posts_ only.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any field like post/posts

Comment: There are no realtime updates for sub-fields...

Comment: So is there a way to get realtime update when a user comments on anywhere?